# Flex/ActionScript: How to copy ListCollectionView variable by value (rather than reference)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How to copy a ListCollectionView variable into a new ListCollectionView variable by value (rather than reference)?

That is, changes to the new ListCollectionView variable should not effect the original ListCollectionView variable (and vice versa).

The end goal is to have 2 ListCollectionView variables pointing to the same ArrayList, but updates to one ListCollectionView variable do not effect the other ListCollectionView variable.

UPDATE 1

Here's one way I found to do it, although I'm not sure if it's the cleanest or most efficient way.

```
LCV2=new ListCollectionView(new ArrayList());
for (var ii:int=0; ii<LCV1.length; ii++) {
    var item:Object=LCV1[ii];
    LCV2.list.addItem(item);
}
```

Comment: How you state the question it's completely impossible, because you both want it to be pointing to the same underlying list/objects but you don't want modifications made via one to those underlying objects to be reflected by the other.  You have to "deep copy" that is clone all the objects in the underlying list and supply that deep copied list as the argument for the other ListCollectionView if you want to keep them from modifying one another.

Comment: Maybe I didn't word it correctly. Changes to the ArrayList are reflected in both ListCollectionView variables. However, changes to one ListCollectionView variable (such as removeAll()), do not effect the other ListCollectionView variable. I'm beginning with one ListCollectionView variable, and I need a second ListCollectionView variable that starts out with the same list as the first ListCollectionView variable, but thereafter acts independently.

Comment: ah okay in that case you are stating it correctly sorry I just misunderstood your meaning... so I think you can just listCollection2.addAll(listCollection1.list); I'll write it in an answer

Comment: I was originally reading into it too much, assuming you meant that updates you made by referencing the underlying objects via the collection views wouldn't be reflected in the other collection view, which would require a deep copy.  Sorry for the oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listCollection1 = new ListCollectionView(event.result); //populate your first list however

listCollection2 = new ListCollectionView(); //create a new ListCollectionView that isn't related to the first
listCollection2.addAll(listCollection1.list); //add all the items from the first list to the second
```

Comment: Thanks Shaunhusain, it appears the `listCollection2.addAll(listCollection1.list);` solution works fine. However, the `listCollection2.list = listCollection1.list;` solution still links the two ListCollectionViews together (changes in one effect the other). Of course, I only need one solution and your first solution is much more clear and succinct than the solution I found above in Update 1. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ggkmath cool I'll remove the other part of the answer then thanks for the feedback

Comment: I find I often have to use `listCollection2=new ListColectionView(new ArrayList());` to avoid FlashBuilder compile time errors.

Comment: In recent versions of Flex this causes an index out of range exception. You can work around this by copying the internal list: listCollection2.list = [create copy from listCollectionView1.list].